# How to vertically align input boxes in an Angular material dialog?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

[image]I have a dialog box, and I have two input fields in the dialog box along with cancel and submit buttons. This is what my box looks like:

[image: Text]]

The input fields are horizontally next to each other, and I really want them to be vertically stacked on top of each other.

When this button is clicked, my modal pops open:

```
    <button class="regular dashboardButtonUI" (click)="openModal(updateModalTemplate)"> Update Task </button>
```

This is my modal template html:

```
    <ng-template #updateModalTemplate>

      <input id="dashboardOldLabels" type="text" readonly=true class="regular h2">
      <input id="dashboardNewLabels" type="text" placeholder="expand the specification here" class="regular h2" >

          <div style="text-align: center;">
          <button mat-button mat-dialog-close class="regular h2 templateDisagreeButton" style="margin-top: 20px; margin: 30px" > Cancel </button>
          <button (click)="delete(task.id)" mat-button mat-dialog-close class="regular h2 templateAgreeButton" style="margin-top: 20px; margin: 30px;"> Update </button>
          </div>

    </ng-template>
```

In my component,

```
constructor(private matDialog:MatDialog){}

  openModal(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>){
    const dialogRef=this.matDialog.open(templateRef,
    {
      width: '400px',
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of handling those situations depending if you use css, scss, a library such as flex-layout, etc. but it all boils down to basic css.

One way would be to add a parent  to your inputs, and tell the div how to position its children.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <input id="dashboardOldLabels" type="text" readonly=true class="regular h2">
  <input id="dashboardNewLabels" type="text" placeholder="expand the specification here" class="regular h2">
</div>
```

If you want your inputs to be centered, you can also ask your div (that is a vertical column) to center the childs on the secondary axis (horizontal row) by adding `align-items: center;`.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
  <input id="dashboardOldLabels" type="text" readonly=true class="regular h2">
  <input id="dashboardNewLabels" type="text" placeholder="expand the specification here" class="regular h2">
</div>
```

[More details about flex and its capabilities](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

For those situations, I personally use [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/). It basically gives you tons of directives to be able to create flex containers and control the behavior of your template without having to manually write your css.

This is what it would look like using flex-layout

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <input id="dashboardOldLabels" type="text" readonly=true class="regular h2">
      <input id="dashboardNewLabels" type="text" placeholder="expand the specification here" class="regular h2">
    </div>
</div>
```